# DOMDocument howto

Tags: php, zend-framework, special-characters, domdocument

Simple question, how to do this with DOMDocument ??

```
<backend>
    <type value="File" />
    <cache_dir>
        <zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH"/>.cache</cache_dir>
</backend>
```

without having the following result:

```
<backend>
    <type value="File"/>
    <cache_dir>&lt;zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH"/&gt;.cache</cache_dir>
</backend>
```

Here what I did:

```
$backendNode = $paramsNode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElement('backend'));
$backendNode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElement('type'))->setAttribute('value', 'File');
$pathnode = $backendNode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElement('cache_dir'));
$pathnode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElement('zf:const'))->setAttribute('zf:name', 'APPLICATION_PATH');
$pathnode->nodeValue .= '.cache';
```

Comment: does it work (in the sense that tags remain tags) if you don't append `'.cache'` to `$pathnode->nodeValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, assuming your namespace `zf` was for Zend framework (and the URI is correct). You have to use the correct namespace functions when manipulating nodes for a specific namespace.

```
$backendNode = $paramsNode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElement('backend'));
$backendNode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElement('type'))->setAttribute('value', 'File');
$pathnode = $backendNode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElement('cache_dir'));
$pathnode->appendChild($cnfXml->createElementNS('http://framework.zend.com/xml/zend-config-xml/1.0/', 'zf:const'))->setAttributeNS('http://framework.zend.com/xml/zend-config-xml/1.0/', 'zf:name', 'APPLICATION_PATH');
$pathnode->appendChild( $cnfXml->createTextNode( '.cache'));
```

This [generated](http://viper-7.com/ZAny3p):

```
<backend>
    <type value="File"/>
    <cache_dir><zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH"/>.cache</cache_dir>
</backend>
```

Comment: great! haven't tought in appending multiple nodes >_<

Comment: so the moral is: don't mess around with `nodeValue` :-)